# Суффикс -ч-

Tags: суффиксы

Есть ли в русских словах отдельный суффикс -ч-? Почему-то я не могу найти ни одной вразумительной ссылки по данному вопросу.
В качестве неформального источника отыскалось вот это :

> **да́-ча**
> Существительное, неодушевлённое, женский род, 1-е склонение (тип склонения 4a по классификации А. Зализняка).
> Корень: -да-; суффикс: -ч; окончание: -а.
> (Викисловарь)

Допустим, что *дача* - слово спорное, и образовано оно штучным способом, по примеру существительных *встреча, сеча*, где -ч- входит в корень (встрет/встреч, сек/сеч)... Давайте возьмем прилагательное *купчая*. Ведь явно же здесь -ч- является суффиксом!  Таких прилагательных в языке много (ловчий, кравчий, гончий, писчий, певчий, зодчий, стряпчий), почему же у них специалисты-языковеды не отмечают отдельный от других суффикс со своим отдельным значением?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему не отмечают? Отмечают. А чем Вам эти ссылки не угодили:  
http://mirslovarei.com/content_efr/ch-a1-suffiks-128442.htm ? Словообразовательная единица, выделяющаяся в именах существительных женского рода, которые обозначают действие по глаголу, названному мотивирующим словом (дача (взятки),выдача, добыча, передача, подача, раздача и т.п.).

http://edudic.ru/efr/129301
 Словообразовательная единица, выделяющаяся в именах прилагательных со значением характеризуемости действием, названным мотивирующим словом (ловчий, купчий, писчий и т.п.).

http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9        Корень: -стряп-; суффикс: -ч; окончание: -ий.

Comment: В Викисловаре я все слова просматривал, в некоторых отмечается этот суффикс. К сожалению, признать викиресурс "академическим" я не могу, многие согласятся с моим мнением. О словах с "основой" -*дача* можно спорить, что там является корнем. То же и по *добыче*. Две другие ссылки, данные Вами, Людмила, как-то неправильно у меня отображаются (?)  
Иногда -к- переходит в -ч- : шибко/шибче, бойко/бойчее. Но в старинных прилагательных -ч- отдельный суффикс, о котором нет приличной статьи НИГДЕ. Очень жаль.

Comment: А так отображаются?

Comment: Вот ещё:
http://rusgram.narod.ru/646-682.htm   § 665.Суф. -ч- |): писать - писчий, ловить - ловчий, купить - купчий , гнать (гонят) и гонять -гончий, петь (с наращением |в1|) - певчий, косить - косчий (косчая трава: обл., встречается в современной художественной прозе). В прилагательных этого типа, называющих признаки животных (гончий, певчий, ловчий), общее значение "характеризующийся действием" конкретизировано как "способный к действию", а в прилагательных, называющих признаки неодушевл. предметов (писчий, косчий), - как "предназначенный или пригодный для осуществления действия".

Comment: Снова что-то со ссылкой. Второй раз не открывается. Но ведь я же скопировала её и содержание тоже. Я не очень на ты с компьютером, поищите сами, набрав "непродуктивные суффиксы старинных прилагательных"

Comment: http://rusgram.narod.ru/646-682.html

Comment: Большое спасибо за русграм! Прямо назван суффикс -ч-, но гугл мне упорно не хотел выдавать этот источник))) Вам , Людмила, надо присвоить знак "Великий Кормчий"!

Answer (score 0):

Словообразовательные модели во всех подробностях зафиксированы в **Русской грамматике** - самом академическом в мире источнике. Суффикс -ч(а) - в параграфе 275:

> § 275. Существительные с суф. -ч(а) (фонемат. |ч|) мотивированы глаголами дать, префиксальными того же корня, удаться, достать (безл.), добыть (суффикс присоединяется к конечной гласной глагольного корня): дача, подача, передача, раздача, отдача, выдача, удача, достача, добыча. Ударение на том же слоге, что и в инфинитиве глагола (акц. тип А). Тип непродуктивный.

*Русскую грамматику* можно скачать, например, здесь: http://infodisk.info/books/rgftx.chm

Comment: Меня устроил §665 (о прилагательных). http://rusgram.narod.ru/646-682.html 
Я считаю, что в существительных типа дача, добыча происходит фонетическое преобразование глагольного суффикса **-ть** по примеру светить - свеча, где корневая т переходит в ч. Соответственно, корень в слове *дача* - **дач**. Новый корень с двумя значениями.  
Пример. Глагол *быть*, в нем есть суффикс или даже два(!) суффикса.
Существительное *быт*, корень -быт-.  
Слова кровно связанные, но корни разные, в существительном суффикс не выделяется. Вот и в словах *задача, передача* не нужно выделять суффикс **-ч**(а)

Comment: В слове _дача_ (загородный дом) корень **дач**. В слове _подача_ корень **да** (оно не утратило родства с формами _подать_, _подам_, _передал_).

Comment: Это все хитронюансы. Все *дачи* - от одного глагола дать/давать. **Б**ыть - **быт**, вот в чем вопрос) Кто здесь кого утратил, какая связь потеряна...  
В словах *шитье, битье, нытье, рытье, бытье, житье, литье, мытье* основа равна инфинитиву глагола, к которому просто приделали окончание. Или тоже будем какой-то суффикс выделять??

Comment: Будем! :-) Русская грамматика, параграф 256:

 -ти|j(е)| и -|т`j(o)|

http://rusgram.narod.ru/256-283.html#256

Comment: >продуктивность морфа -ти|j|- ограничена определенным набором глагольных корней...  

Даже примеры не приведены этих самых слов. Ясно, что слова - древние, позже были придуманы специальные суффиксы (-ани, -ени) для отглагольных существительных. Литература древнерусская требовала развития языка, и оно воспоследовало. А первые подобные слова (житие, питие, бытие...) были составлены простейшим способом : ифинитив + окончание. Иначе объяснить совпадение того, что современные ученые называют "суффиксами" (би**ть**/би**ть**е) - невозможно.

Не было тыщу лет назад "суффиксов"! Но потом появились.

Comment: Древние слова (инфинитив + окончание), позже слегка модифицированные (ти/ть) :
житье, бытье, мытье...  
Современные :  
проживание, пребывание, промывание...  
Как видно, добавилось со временем и приставок, и суффиксов, и еще кой-чего. Язык развивается и усложняется постепенно, согласно с требованиями века. Десятый век не равен двадцатому.